# GCM - how to selectively send messages to certain package names?

Tags: android, build, google-cloud-messaging, variants

We have a project with **three build variants**: *dev, tst, live* and respective **package names** *our.package.name.dev, our.package.name.tst, our.package.name*. All build variants have different back-ends so we need to display **different push notifications for different variants**.

The Server API key in the developers console is not connected with any certain build variant/package name, so it sends out to all build flavours.

Is there a designated way to approach this problem? The only solution I currently see, is to send the target build variant with the GCM data and check in the front-end.

Comment: When you manually registered with GCM, to get an `sender id` (12 digit number) and an `API key` (39 char alphanumeric), did you provide your `package name` then? That's what I got asked for, which indicated I needed to use the right identifier in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an option [`restricted_package_name`](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-plain-text). This parameter specifies the package name of the application where the registration tokens must match in order to receive the message.